# I am having issues while writing to a single node hadoop cluster on EC2

Tags: python, hadoop, amazon-ec2, hdfs

I am trying to write to a Hadoop cluster(HDFS) from a different EC2 machine and I am getting error when trying to do so. However I am able to read the data over the port 50070 but when trying to write it gives me connection refused error.

Setup: Single Node Hadoop cluster installed on EC2 and I am trying to connect to it from different EC2 instance which does not have Hadoop installed on it.

Scenario: I am trying to write to this single node Hadoop cluster from different servers (Ec2 instances) over the port 50070 but I am getting connection refused error in doing so, however if I do the same thing on the local Hadoop server it works.

Error:

```
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError:   <requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f327c0c1810>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: does `50070 ` port accessible from other EC2 instance ?

Comment: Yes I am able read the data using the following command "curl -i  "http://<HOST>:<PORT>/webhdfs/v1/<PATH>?op=LISTSTATUS"

Comment: The error you provided clearly states that connection is refused on that port - that might mean the app is either not listening on this port or it's blocked by firewall. By default, on EC2, it would timeout instead of refuse. Please paste the command you are using to write.